# Moving ASP.NET Website to new computer

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to move my asp.net website from one computer to another. What would be the best way to do this? I have already downloaded all the correct programs to be able to run the website, I just want to know the best way to actually move the website folder without having any issues.

Comment: Assuming all your paths and everything else are correct and permissions for the new machine, just copy paste.  There are a lot of settings/etc you have to worry about on the new machine to make sure they match.  As well as any firewalls or anything if you have DB

Comment: This is too broad of a question for Stack Overflow: we can't list all the possibilities because we don't know your application. It's up to you to move it and then resolve any issues that arise.

Comment: I don't know what we're supposed to tell you besides copy the files and make sure everything you need is installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option to use git in both computers. Commit from one and clone from another.  But I prefer a portable device and move the whole solution folder. Not sure whether it answered your question. :)

Answer (score -1):

It's as simple as copying the files onto a flash drive and dropping them in the new computer's file path of your choice. From there you open Visual studio, Click Open Project/Solution, and go to the file path and choose the Project/Solution you want to use.

Comment: Nope, not that simple. Does it have the right version of .NET? Does it have the right IIS modules? How do you know it's being run in Visual Studio and not on a server?  If it is VS do they have the right extensions and components installed? Does the application depend on a database? Is the DB server software installed? What about folder structures or other external dependencies? See how this is extremely broad and not nearly as simple as you stated? You shouldn't have attempted to answer this question, it's too broad.